# Jenkins docker missing some binaries

Tags: linux, shell, jenkins, docker

I am running Jenkins in docker from official [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/) .

I created job which runs my own shell script, however I see some binaries 
are missing in docker e.g.`file` command.

They mention on docker hub that one can install additional binaries over Ubuntu's `aptitude` however I don't know which package to install to get e.g `file` command working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless Ubuntu did something different than the base Debian environment, file is included in the file package.

```
apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -f file
```